# Python: Second part of loop breaking

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I'm trying to create a simple back propagation script. As it stands now, my code will go through a single iteration (i.e., `for j in xrange(1)`), but if I try to add in more iterations, the script breaks.

I think I am changing the format of some of my variables, but I'm not sure why or how to fix this.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import math

def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
        return x*(1-x)

    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def frange(start, stop, step):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += step

A = []
B = []

for i in frange(-2,2,0.1):
    t = np.exp(-abs(i))*sin(i*math.pi)
    A.append(i)
    B.append(t)

X = np.array(A)
y = np.array(B)
# randomly initialize our weights with uniformly distributed [-.5,.5]
weight = np.random.uniform([-.5,.5])

syn0 = weight[0]
syn1 = weight[1]

for j in xrange(2):

# Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
    a0 = X
    a1 = nonlin(np.dot(a0,syn0))
    a2 = nonlin(np.dot(a1,syn1))

# how much did we miss the target value?
    a2_error = y - a2

    if (j% 100) == 0:
        print "Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(a2_error)))

# in what direction is the target value?
# were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    s2_delta = a2_error*nonlin(a2,deriv=True)

# how much did each k1 value contribute to the k2 error (according to the weights)?
    a1_error = s2_delta.dot(syn1.T)

# in what direction is the target k1?
# were we really sure? if so, don't change too much.
    s1_delta = a1_error * nonlin(a1,deriv=True)

    syn1 += a1.T.dot(s2_delta)
    syn0 += a0.T.dot(s1_delta)
```

After a single iteration, I get an error printed out (which is good), but on further runs through the loop it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HW4.py", line 40, in <module>
    a1 = nonlin(np.dot(a0,syn0))
  File "HW4.py", line 9, in nonlin
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
```

Comment: How does your code break? Can we see the updated code with multiple iterations? What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: What do you mean by 'breaks'? Which error do you get?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I've added more of the code and provided the error that is output. The purpose of this is to update the random starting weights based on the errors of the previous iteration.

Comment: Whats the exception? You have given the traceback but not the cause of the exception.